# Modular approach for pluralizing nouns

Tags: php

I think we've all run into the issue before where an app says that there are "1 minutes remaining", or something along those lines. I think this observation is a testament to the fact that many programmers ignore this issue.

In my projects, I've typically done something along these lines to account for pluralizing nouns:

```
$Count = count($Items);
$Noun = 'minute';
if ($Count != 1)
{
    $Noun .= 's';
}

echo sprintf('There are %u %s remaining.', $Count, $Noun);
```

I have a couple issues with this approach:

1. It places the onus on the programmer to do this pluralization check every single time a string needs to be generated, so code can never be reused.
2. It needlessly bloats the application code and inhibits readability.
3. It is not generic. The example worked because "minutes" is the plural of "minute". What about "sheep", "ox", or "fungus"?

Does anyone have any ideas for a generic, modular approach to solve this problem? I'm ok with there being more than just one answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common to implement a function that accepts a number and all singular and plural adjectives.

So sample invocation could be

```
echo 'There are ' $count . ' ' . pluralize($count, array('minute', 'minutes')) . ' remaining';
```

If you'll decide to translate your application into many languages this link will help to pluralize correctly: http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/l10n/pluralforms

ps: the propisal I made will work fine with any languages in case if you pass additional 3rd parameter `language` that will specify which pluralization formula to use.

Comment: Thanks for giving a simple solution as well as an ideal one. I definitely think this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I think that using a general approach will overstress the performance against the usefulness of this little code. To achieve a generic approach you should use a dictonary or something like this which is really unnecessary compared to the benefits. Maybe a more simple line like this is the right trade off between performance and usefullness.

```
$Count = count($Items);
$Noun = 'minute';
echo sprintf('There are %u %s(s) remaining.', $Count, $Noun);
```

Comment: Such small things is what makes software something sexy. Otherwise it is just a sketch without pluralization and correct "him/her" usages.

Comment: @zerkms If we're talking about the beauty of doing this kind of thing, I very much agree with you. If we are talking about doing this kind of print optimization in a little/medium software, I see no real benefits.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to handle this would be to create a function that takes three arguments: the number, the singular spelling of the word, and the pluralized spelling of the word. The function returns either the singular or pluralized version of the word, depending on the value. It still puts the onus on the programmer, but it's cleaner than what you show here.

Comment: What if he'll decide to implement i18n for his app? Arabic has 6 plural forms, thus the function need to accept 6 arguments, not 2.

Comment: @zerkms, this is a good point. good thing you posted an answer that addresses it ;-)